# create zip file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create zip file using codeigniter
here is my code

```
$this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE);
$this->zip->archive($path . '.zip');
```

Code is creating zip file properly. But when I extract zip, files are inside the folder.

Here is my folder structure

```
config
   /abc.xml
   /index.html
   /images
        /logo.png
   /data
```

When I try to compress config folder, while extracting new config folder created. Is there any way to compress only files and folder which are inside config folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could, by reading the directory yourself and after that invoking `$this->zip->read_file()` on each separate file. Something along these lines (not tested):

```
$files = array();
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!is_dir($entry)) {
            $files[] = $entry;
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

foreach($files as $file) {
    $this->zip->read_file($file);
}
```